# Cannot run an application from udev script

Tags: linux, udev

In our embedded system, we have properly set udev to run a script located in /etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh. This works very well. However, we cannot successfully run an application from inside this script.

This is very weird. We tried to write this application call in a script, say test.sh. If we call test.sh from udev script (mount.sh), nothing happened. It only works if we call test.sh from the shell.

Does anyone know what's the problem here?

**Updated:**
test.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/app/appipc "[header]usb,add"
```

appipc is just a simple Qt application to use QLocalSocket to connect to a local server by name. If we run this script in shell, it works. But not from udev script (mount.sh).

Comment: would you share the script error message what it says when you run? it never runs

Comment: The script runs well in shell, so there is no error message. Do  you mean when it was run by udev script? I am not sure how to determine the error generated from there.

Comment: Did you try the system log?

Comment: Yes. We tried to use syslog in the appipc. Running from shell we can see the output message from /var/log/messages, but running from udev script we see nothing there. We doubt that any situation to make the appipc unable to run from udev script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally we figured out that, the Qt lib was not able to load correctly if we run a Qt application from udev script. That's why we doubt it never runs. If we run a regular C application, everything works well!

This is kind of silly and negligent of us! We should consider this in advance. Thanks everyone for the time.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with compiling Qt with udev support on/off?