# How can I create a udev rule to run a script when USB store is plugged in?

Tags: linux, udev

I need to run a Python or a shell script whenever a USB is plugged in.

So I need to create a [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) rule for that.

Comment: Sure, go ahead! What prevents you from doing that? Maybe check [ask] and look for some tutorials or the udev documentation.

Comment: Stack Exchange site *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)* happily accepts such work orders. No questions asked.

Comment: In any case, this is very likely a duplicate. Where is the canonical question?

Comment: Some starting points (not canonical; low scored): *[Run script with udev after USB plugged in on a Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295198/)*, *[Cannot run an application from udev script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391115)*, and *[Play music from a Bash script running from 'udev'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63620745)*.

Comment: [297 candidates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=udev+run+script)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a *udev* rules file. For example, you can add the file
*/etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules*:

Its content can be:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEMS=="block", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/systemctl start usb-mount@%k.service"

KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEMS=="block", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/bin/systemctl stop usb-mount@%k.service"
```

The previous is a udev rules file that starts and stops the [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) service *usb-mount@.service* by [`systemctl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd#Core_components_and_libraries).
By this service file you can start the desired Python or Bash script.

A content example for the service file is the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount USB Drive on %i

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/usb-mount.sh add %i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/usb-mount.sh remove %i
```

Inside the unit file you can find the options *ExecStart* and *ExecStop* that start the Bash script */usr/bin/usb-mount.sh*.
The script accepts two arguments:

1. `add` | `remove`
2. the name of the USB device file (`sda`, `sdb`, `sdb1`, and so on).

So *usb-mount.sh* is called when you insert (`ACTION==add` in the udev rule) or remove (`ACTION==remove` in the udev rule) a USB storage device.